# Simple.Mocking Expect method call with custom object

Tags: c#, unit-testing

So I am using Simple.Mocking to Mock some interfaces on my tests. Some methods receive custom objects

```
public class MyObj
{
    public int Attr { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as MyObj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Attr;
    }

    private bool Equals(MyObj myObj)
    {
        return Attr == myObj.Attr;
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void Show(MyObj o);
}

public class ObjUnderTest
{
    public ObjUnderTest(IFoo foo)
    {
        var o = new MyObj{ Attr = 1; };
        foo.Show(o);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClasse
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestShow()
    {
        var foo = Mock.Interface<IFoo>();
        var myObj = new MyObj { Attr = 1 };
        Expect.Once.MethodCall(() => foo.Show(myObj));

        var objectUnderTest = new ObjUnderTest(foo);

        AssertExpectations.IsMetFor(foo);
    }
}
```

The problems is that test fails always, even when `Show` is called with a object with `Attr`equals to 1. It only pass if I write the expect like this:

```
Expect.Once.MethodCall(()=> foo.Show(Any<MyObj>.Value));
```

Which is not what I need. I know it fails because those are different objects but I have tried overriding `MyObj` `Equals` and `GetHashCode` with no success.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of the problem. Current example is incomplete.

Comment: @Nkosi It is done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired outcome is to validate the input you can try specifying exptectation with a predicate

```
Expect.Once.MethodCall(()=> foo.Show(Any<MyObj>.Value.Matching(obj => obj.Attr == 1)));
```

Source: project readme on Github - [Using "wildcard" parameter values](https://github.com/mikaelwaltersson/Simple.Mocking/#using-wildcard-parameter-values)

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClasse {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestShow() {
        //Arrange
        var foo = Mock.Interface<IFoo>();
        Expect.Once.MethodCall(()=> foo.Show(Any<MyObj>.Value.Matching(obj => obj.Attr == 1)));
        //Act
        var objectUnderTest = new ObjUnderTest(foo);
        //Assert
        AssertExpectations.IsMetFor(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually have more than one property to check on equality but your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Yes this answer was just an example to build up on based on original question. Happy coding!!!